# 18650 Cell boost converter to 4.8v (not 5v)

Tags: led, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion, boost, batteries

I have a torch in which 3 AAA cells are put in (1.6 (new AAA) * 3 =4.8v). The problem is these are not long lasting and i have to change them after few days. What i am looking for is a rechargeable option. I cannot use 1.2v Ni-Cd(1.2 * 3 = 3.6v) regargeble as the voltage is too low and led is dim.
Recently i extracted 18650 (LGABD11865) batteries from my Old Dell Laptop.

I used powerbank module to test it out with my torch light. The output is slighltly over 5v (around 5.11) and the light consumes around 1.3Amps. When the voltage is reduced to 4.8v (checked through power supply) the amps are reduced to 1 Amp which is reasonable as it wont consume more battery and the torch wouldnt heat up.

Can someone please help me in this regard i have very basic knowledge of Electronics i need 4.8v CV with atmost 1 Amps.  Furthermore the torch can only take 1 18650 Battery along with 1 tp4056 charging module or small powerbank module (usb type A port removed). [image][image]

Update: I used 3 new AAA  batteries in the casing which came with the torch. The voltage when measured showed 5.01v but the current at full brightness was 0.5amps. I need a resister MOSFET anything which can lower the current input to the torch. At present when connected with 5v supply the torch takes around 1.23 amps.

Comment: If the 5v regulator can remain in the circuit, you may wish to consider a flashlight driver based on the ubiquitous AMC7135 low drop out linear current regulator.  Your best options would be 2 suitably protected 18650s in series with a buck type current regulator or 1 suitably protected 18650 with a boost type current regulator.  Originally the flashlights protection from thermal runaway may have been the internal resistance and diminishing output of the battery, so make sure you don't neglect current control if you're switching to a low impedance battery type.

Comment: Battery protection circuits are sometimes in cells, and sometimes in the device that contains the cells.  Since you are taking cells from an unknown device, you should assume they are unprotected until you confirm otherwise, and never charge *or* discharge a lithium ion battery without suitable protection circuits.

Comment: Also just be aware that there are tons of available compact LED drivers like the luxeon Buckpuck and Boostpuck and their knockoffs, and there exists a subset of flashlight parts that can be bought individually, including casings, lenses, LEDs, drivers, controllers and switches.  Parts and machining cost money, so before you buy stuff to modify an existing flashlight, you may wish to check out Convoy to see if you can get a better whole flashlight for cheaper than the cost of the mod.  An S12 is 30 maple dollars and compares well against much more expensive lights.

Comment: On the other hand, if getting into electronics is your goal, messing with flashlights is good experience, and the biggest challenge I find with considering a mod to an existing light, is getting enough room in the casing for whatever parts you need to add.  If your original light didn't come with a current regulator board, it usually doesn't have room or threading allotted to mount that extra board, so if you want to consider changing the battery, you also have to find enough room for the extra circuits in the springs or by shrinking the battery.

Comment: Have you taken apart the lens end of your flashlight to see what drives the LED?

Comment: Thankyou K H for your response. I have a small LED which came with 3AAA casing in it which could be replaced by 1 18650 battery and there is little space left on the side where tp4056 or a powerbankmodule 5v/1a can easily be adjusted to charge the battery..  i cannot access the LED driver which is lock into the housing where LEDismounted i tried opening but failed. So the only option left  is to reduce the voltag from powerbank module.. i have a suggestion caniuse Schottky diode in series lets say 1N5819 which would decrease voltage but the max current rating is 1amps which is less.

Comment: Is there any other diode withvoltag drop of around 0.3 to 0.5 volts? With atleast maximum current rating of 1.5 amps? I donot want to use 1N5819 as it would be running at its full potential at 1amps and will easily burn.

Comment: @K H yes i have and i have updated my question with the circuit board picture. There are 2 (1 ohm) resistors, a capacitor and HD14e SMD which i did try finding it on google and couldnt find it.

Comment: Hmm a better picture of the circuit board would help.  You need to figure out what's connected to what in what order to guess at what that SMD does.  Is the control board screwed in from the inside of the torch so you'd have to desolder the LED's to get it out?

Comment: Are you running your 5V tests directly to the LED or through the existing circuitry?  You're talking about a wide range of currents through the LED, but at the end of your post you're talking about applying 5.01v and getting only 0.5A of current.  Are you measuring that 5.01V while the LED is on?  You should be getting less voltage from those triple As under load.  That voltage converter just draws more power from the battery to maintain the same output voltage, so it acts like it has no internal resistance.

Comment: Aah that would be an issue i tried getting th conteol board out but failed i believe if i keep on trying i would break the board. The board is not screwed i still cant figure it out how the board is fixed within the torch. I believe it is glued or soldered somehow.  I will try getting a better picture but there are only 4 components on the led driver board which includes

Comment: 2 (1R0 Resisters), 1 (Capacitor) and 1 HD14e.

Comment: @K H you are probably right. Sorry for the confusion. I was running 5v tests through th circuit board. I measured the AAA voltage before connecting it to the circuit so you probably is right about voltage drop. I would try again today to measure the voltage across AAAs when giving it to the LED through Circuit Board.

Comment: You could also measure the voltage across the LED to get a rough idea of whats correct and then apply less input voltage to get a matching current.  If you match the load voltage of the batteries this way you should be relatively safe, but if the voltage drop you need is too much you'll waste a lot of power and produce a lot of heat.  Nothing wrong with testing to find out how much the voltage drop is, but for getting a workable and safe flashlight there's a good chance the 5v low impedance output isn't suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You say that your knowledge of electronics is very basic, so I shall not recommend a bespoke design.  It’s normal to use a constant-current driver for LEDs, not least because the current is very sensitive to the voltage applied.  If you can find a constant current driver that fits your requirements then you’re all good, although I think you may struggle because of the relatively low supply voltage.  As an alternative you might try using a resistor to limit the current:  you want to supply 1A to the LED and the resistor should drop (5.1 - 4.8) = 0.3V.  Using Ohm’s law, R=V/I so you’ll need a 0.3 ohm resistor with a power rating of at least 0.3W.  The nearest thing you’ll easily find is a 0.33 ohm part with 0.5W power rating.  If you place this in series with the LED you should be ok.  I note that 1A is a lot to ask from AA cells, so you may well be overdriving the LED which will shorten its life.  If you use a larger value resistor you’ll get slightly lower output but longer battery life, perhaps try 0.47 ohm.  As an aside, there are some good reasons why resistors have these oddball values - look up ‘preferred value resistor’ if you’d like to know more.

Comment: Using a resistor with such small resistance may not successfully achieve current regulation of the LED.  The resistor must waste enough power that it heats up enough in comparison to the LED that it's positive temperature coefficient cancels out the negative temperature coefficient of the LED, or thermal runaway will occur.  For very small voltage drops, a low drop out linear current regulator is best.  This can be aided by keeping the resistor thermally close to the LED's heat sink to ensure the resistor heats up from the LED's dissipated power as well.

Comment: Quite so, but this may be beyond the capabilities of the OP, with all due respect, and the OP has indicated that the LED is ok in the short term at least, I suspect because the 5V boost converter is current-limiting, do any additional resistance will improve stability further.  Also, protection against thermal runaway doesn’t rely on the tempco of the resistor.

Comment: Thermal runaway is caused by the decreasing resistance as the LED heats up increasing current and causing a compounding effect.  If the temperature coefficient of the entire circuit comes out negative, you get thermal runaway.  This only matters with tight voltage drops like the one here, but also matters more for power LEDS.

Comment: To see this effect in action, you can take a power LED mounted on an aluminum star and apply a constant voltage to get it's rated current.  Then leave the voltage applied and monitor current while the LED heats up and burns out.  Then try adding a very small resistor in series, suitable to cause a .2 or so volt drop, and repeat the procedure with larger resistors until the LED no longer burns out.  This is the destructive testing way to find an adequate temperature coefficient compensation.

Comment: Thankyou All for your informative responses. I would like to add a suggestion. I just found out a powerbank module on Aliexpress which has output 5v/1A and can be connected with 18650 battery. Will this work if i connect it with my LED? Will itlimit current input? And Frog you are probably right about shortening life of my LED because it does heat up if we use it at full power with 1amps. Instead of limiting current i would want to decrease voltage which would automatically decrease its current input. Is there a way to make it 4.6v - 4.8v? I wouldnt go below 4.6v as it dims the light. Thankyou

Comment: @Zulqurnain You're missing the core concept.  Read up on thermal runaway in LEDs.  If you don't use current control, the only alternative is to use so much cooling that the LED can't heat up, so you're looking at huge oversized heatsinks or wasting power on fans.  If you do want to go this way with it, Just as an example, I have a 5 watt RGBW LED that I mounted to a 100W CPU heatsink.  For short tests, I can PWM with more than their rated voltage without cooking them, and at rated voltage it takes about 10 minutes for thermal runaway to become noticable instead of 30 seconds to a minute.

Comment: All of that said, some cheaper LED flashlight heads use resistors on the LED PCB rather than a current controller, so there is some chance that your LED is voltage control tolerant, but without at least series resistors, constant voltage is almost certain to thermal runaway and cook the LEDs.  The saving grace of your voltage regulator is the 1 amp current limit, as when it gets close to 1 amp it will likely have some voltage dip, which can help, but keeping that circuit in a state of constantly limiting current when it's not designed to do so is likely to produce bad results or damage.

Comment: Aside from the thermal runaway, the important concept here is that small changes in voltage make a big difference to the current (and power) so it’s much better to control the current somehow.  Possibly you’d be ok with a 1A power bank if it automatically limits current to 1A.  Some do that, I’m sure, but others may shut down if they get to maximum current, others may overheat.

Comment: @K H and @Frog please see the updated part in the question i have added picture of circuit board and added new findings.

Comment: Ooh there’s a circuit board in there - if you can get to it, can you post photos of both sides?  Possibly a component change there will give you what you want.

Comment: @Frog these are the all for components soldered on the LED driver Board. The other side of the board has only negative and positive terminal for the battery. Where negative sticks to the body of the torch. I did try getting it out but failed. I am afraid that i would break it if i try doing this.